# Inverse Vector3

Tags: java, c++

I'm trying to convert some C++ code into Java. As there is no default Vector3 datatype in java, I have created my own custom Vector3 class. However, I saw that it is possible to do this: 1/VECTOR3 in C++. This had me sort of confused as a Vector3 has 3 values within it. So I was wondering could someone explain to me what is actually happening to each of the 3 values when 1/VECTOR3 is used?

The code I'm trying to convert is from here, at the bottom of the page:
https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-box-intersection

```
class Ray  {  public: 
    Ray(const Vec3f &orig, const Vec3f &dir) : orig(orig), dir(dir) 
    { 
        invdir = 1 / dir; 
        sign[0] = (invdir.x < 0); 
        sign[1] = (invdir.y < 0); 
        sign[2] = (invdir.z < 0); 
    } 
    Vec3 orig, dir;       // ray orig and dir 
    Vec3 invdir; 
    int sign[3];  };
```

Comment: There is no `Vector3` type in C++ by default either.

Comment: Standard C++ dowsn't have `VECTOR3`. Whatis `1/VECTOR3`?

Comment: C++ lets you define what operators mean when used on your own types, by defining a function named `operator/`. There's probably a `Vec3f operator/(float, Vec3f const&)` somewhere in the library that website is using. Java doesn't have that; you have to use normally named functions/methods. In the end, it's the same thing: it's just library code. The only difference is how nice it looks.

Comment: What is the definition of `1/Vector`?  I don't understand the result of a single number divided by a 3 dimensional matrix or any data stucture.  Are you talking an inverse?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no `Vec3` in C++. If you read that page carefully, its all their types. The text is a bit sloppy. They call it "inverse of the ray-direction" but for a vector I am not aware of a commonly used defintion for "inverse". Anyhow...

You just need to scroll to the end of the page, follow the link to the complete example, then look at `geometry.h`. There is the definition of that division:

```
friend Vec3 operator / (const T &r, const Vec3 &v) 
{ return Vec3<T>(r / v.x, r / v.y, r / v.z); }
```

(`T` is the element type)

They define division of a scalar by a vector to be element-wise division.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to User: *idclev 463035818*. I found out that for [this specific paper](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-box-intersection) essentially **this operation was a custom operation made in c#** (because apparently, c# is just that overpowered). When you have a number, that we'll call ***n*** divided by vector3 that we'll call ***VECTOR3***. Essentially, each this operation returns the following as a vector3 **(*n / VECTOR3.x*, *n / VECTOR3.y*, *n / VECTOR3.z*)**